# If condition with a time parameter

Tags: c++, qt

I have got a basic question. I'm getting sensor value from a serial device , I have the following condition to check.

```
if(y_acc > accThreshold) 
      {
        ui->rdo_btn->show();
        setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOn);

      }

else
      {    
        setStyleSheet(StyleSheetOff);
      }
```

Here how do I include a time condition, for ex. `if(y_acc > accThreshold)` **for more than 200ms** then set `StyleSheetOn`, else other.

I can get the time elapsed since the start, in seconds (say it's `key`).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way would be :
the first time your condition is meet :

arm a QTimer single shot  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop  connected to your stylesheet change or anything you need to do.

upon new value coming, if the value is not reaching the condition , stop the timer. otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Do I need a signal and slot connection for that? Can you show me an example please?